# Codeigniter error con SSL

Tags: codeigniter, ssl, https

tengo un aplicativo en mi entorno local bajo Codeigniter.

Con HTTP me funciona correctamente, pero necesito cambiarlo a HTTPS

He creado los certificados para mi url y accedo correctamente a la página principal que es un formulario de login.

```
https://misitio.local.org
```

El problema es que cuando envío el formulario al controlador para validar en BD me da un error 500.

```
https://misitio.local.org/index.php/users/login
```

En el fichero **config.php** tengo esto:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://misitio.local.org';

$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/; SameSite=None';
$config['cookie_secure']    = TRUE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

En apache tengo así definido el **virtualhosts**

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/DES_new/misitio">
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:443>

DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/DES_new/misitio/httpdocs"
ServerName misitio.local.org
ServerAlias misitio.local.org
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ErrorLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/error_ssl_misitio.log"
TransferLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/access_ssl_misitio.log"

SSLEngine on

SSLCertificateFile "C:/xampp/apache/conf/mis_certificados/todas.pem"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/xampp/apache/conf/mis_certificados/todas-key.pem"

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "C:/xampp/apache/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
CustomLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/ssl_request.log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>
```

Y el **.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade"
</IfModule>
```

En el fichero log de apache aparece este error

```
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Feb/2021:13:46:02 +0100] "POST /index.php/users/login HTTP/1.1" 500 1236
```

¿Alguna sugerencia de porqué no accedo al sitio?

Saludos

Comment: Esa URL es muy rara: `https://misitio.local.org/index.php/users/login`, ¿qué intentas hacer con una URL escrita así? ¿Por qué no implementas URLs amigables? ¿Si intentas navegar sólo a `https://misitio.local.org/index.php` qué ocurre?

Comment: Esa url es la llamada interna a un método de un controlador de Codeigniter, que después de verificar el usuario muestra una vista.
El cliente accede a aplicativo mediante *https://misitio.local.org* Con lo cual las urls, sí son amigables.

Muestra esa url porque es donde se produce el error, que he recuperado de consola.

Comment: Con quien estas generando tus certificados de seguridad, 
Esto es un poco raro porque no veo la configuracion de tu dominio local:
SSLCertificateFile "C:/xampp/apache/conf/mis_certificados/todas.pem"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/xampp/apache/conf/mis_certificados/todas-key.pem"